# class must either be declared abstract or implement convertToLegacyCheckingEqualizer

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I wrote a simple Test case in IntelliJ 2017.1 Ultimate. And I see an absolutely bogus error message in IntelliJ

```
class must either be declared abstract or implement convertToLegacyCheckingEqualizer
```

My code compiles and runs absolutely fine but IntelliJ edition always shows this message for each and every test class.

I googled and found totally unsatisfactory answers like

```
* I restarted my IDE to solve the problem
* I deleted my idea project and recreated it to solve the problem
* I cleared ivy cache to solve the problem.
```

This solutions are just wrong and don't really address the problem.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a simple, one-class project that illustrates the problem? Are your using _SBT_? Are your using the _IntelliJ Scala_ plugin (I'm assuming you are, but it's not obvious from your question.) Without seeing the definition of your code, and your _IntelliJ_ configuration, it's impossible to help you.

Comment: I took a screenshot of the problem. Yes I am using SBT and Scala Plugin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give this a try: in *IntelliJ*, go to the **File** menu, then select the **Invalidate Caches / Restart...** option. On the resulting dialog, click the **Invalidate and Restart** button.

After *IntelliJ* has restarted, check whether you still have the same problem.

Comment: After IntelliJ restarts, I still have the same problem :-(

Comment: @FriedBrice It might pay to run `sbt clean` (exit from _IntelliJ_ first, and run this from the command line), then invalidate the caches in _IntelliJ_ a second time. If that fails, it might also be necessary to clear your _Ivy_ cache as well, then repeat these steps once more.

Comment: Deleted ~/.m2, ~/.sbt, ~/.ivy2, ~/.scalac, and deleted and recloned project directory. Same problem :-( I'll continue googling. Thanks for the help, @MikeAllen :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience. I eventually found that the problem was a missing JDK. I upgraded my system JDK and deleted the old one without changing it in the project settings. Changing it in the project settings made everything work :-)

Comment: @FriedBrice Hmmm. That's good to know! In case it helps anyone else, what were the versions of the JDK that you had, and that you were missing?

Comment: It was 1.8.0_15x, and it's not 1.8.0_162. A `brew upgrade` brought in the new version of Java, and my Project Structure in IntelliJ was incorrectly configured to point to the literal 1.8.0_15x dir instead of using my JAVA_HOME environment variable. I set it to use JAVA_HOME so future upgrades won't break my projects.